# c# Rgb color change on graphics with textbox's

Tags: c#

The code i've done in form has 3 boxes and one Rectangle from e.Graphics. 
I've made it so the every textbox is attached to the button where the change of color should happen but it doesn't work.
I think i should apply "System.Drawing" but i don't know how. 
Thanks

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int x = 150;


    int red = 0x33, green = 55, blue = 0x77;


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        red = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(0, green, blue);
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(red, green, 0);



    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        green = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(red, 0, blue);


    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Color myRgbColor = new Color();
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x, 20, 100, 100);
        myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);

        {


        }
    }

    private void btnKlick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Color myRgbColor = new Color(); 
        myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);






    }

    public Color myRgbColor { get; set; }


    public object FromArgb { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: You create Colors but they are discarded after each TextChanged event. Why?? Your Paint event only Fill a red rectangle. What else do you want??? Maybe add a `using (Pen pen = new Pen(myRgbColor  )); g.DrawRectanlge(pen, x, 20, 100, 100);` in the Paint curlys and an `Invalidate()` an the end of each textChanged event..

Comment: To change the color of the rectangle using the boxes and the button to execute.

Comment: Sigh. You got it all in reverse. __First__ create the color, __then__ a brush from it! You can do it all in the Paint event. The you can use the Brsuh to fill the rectanlge.. Did you add the `Invalidate()`s in the TextChanged? Come back after these changes!

Comment: When i did the reverse everything seem to be ok however nothing has changed. In the brush i tried "new SoildBrush(Color.FromArgb); but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've fixed the the boxes.

Comment: So it works now as you want it to?